# PHP Shorthand Boolean

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I'm trying to shorten the following. Essentially I want to always get the value of the lefthand as long as $object isn't null, otherwise use a default value.

```
if ($object) {
    $isManual = $object->getIsManual(); // either true or false
} else {
    $isManual = true;
}
```

The following doesn't work since getIsManual can return false which makes it use the righthand.

```
$isManual = $object ? $object->getIsManual() : true;
```

Any work arounds? Currently on PHP 7.4.

Comment: You *shouldn't* shorten this code, as that sacrifices **readability**. But if you really want to... `$isManual = ($object ?: new class() {function getIsManual() {return true;})->getIsManual();` Hmm... not really shorter...

Comment: Wait... your shortened code already works. What's the problem?

Comment: The first and second code snippets do the exact same job and there's no problem using the second code snippet. May I ask what do you mean by "lefthand" and "righthand", and what do you mean by "makes it use the righthand"? Thanks

Comment: Your code should work as is.

Comment: Second snippet doesn't work because IF $object->getIsManual() returns false, then it will end up using the righthand (true), but it should be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify - the return value of `getIsManual()` wouldn't affect the condition, it only evaluates `$object` to be 'true' or 'false' (which include null).

You can explicitly check for null in the condition...

```
$isManual = is_null($object) ? true : $object->getIsManual();
```

Note that I've reversed the order of the values as I prefer to say is `is_null` rather than using a not as well.